# Ocultar inputs por defecto en Node-RED

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

estoy haciendo un nodo, en **node-red** y me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para que los campos con **checkbox** aparezcan ocultos por defecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se ve como al clickar en el nodo se ven los checkbox desmarcados y su correspondiente input está visible, si marco y desmarco el checkbox ya si se oculta.

Lo que quiero es que aparezca oculto desde primera hora.

Adjunto código javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDay() {
        check = document.getElementById("node-input-showDay");
        element = document.getElementById("contentDay");
        if (check.checked) {
            element.style.display = 'inline-block';
        } else {
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

y código html del input:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
        <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-showDay" type="checkbox" name="checkeo" onchange="showDay()"> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Choose a day:
        <label class="form-check-label" for="showDay"></label>
        <span id="contentDay">
            <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-day" type="date" name="day">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="day"></label>
            </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Prueba usando lo mismo para ocultarlo pero al cargar la página [1)DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)  [2)Load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)  [3)Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Comment: A qué se refiere?

Comment: ¿Podés modificar directamente el css/js o se genera automáticamente?

Comment: Puedo modificarlos, si.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que hacés que se oculten cuando cambian de estado (`onchange="showDay()"`). Podrías solucionarlo agregando una regla en el css para que comiencen ocultos:

```
#contentDay{
  display: none;
}
```

O ejecutando `showDay()` al cargar la página (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload):

```
window.onload = function() {
  showDay();
};
```

Lo más normal creo que es agregar una regla en el css que sea algo así:

```
// css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}

// html
<span id="contentDay" class="hidden"> ...

// js
function showDay(){
  ...
  element.classList.remove("hidden");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Si ya estás usando un framework de estilos de node-red, seguro tenga una clase que ya cumple la funcion de `hidden` en el ejemplo.